# A notable collapse

Tags: word, wordplay

> Larry Leprechaun was dancing on a table,
>   but keeping balance, he was not able.
>   Falling, he nearly did _____ himself,
>   and wailed "__ __!" while some guy said "Give this __ __" .

Find one word, split sometimes, which may complete the blanks.

Comment: I think he was dancing on no table.

Comment: Except it would have been stout, obviously.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The word is

> Impale

Reasoning

> Larry Leprechaun was dancing on a table,
>  but keeping balance, he was not able.
> Falling, he nearly did **impale** himself,
>  and wailed "**I'm pale**!" while some guy said "Give this **imp ale**" .